# How to search patents using inventors name

Tags: design-patent

Gustave F Ockrassa is my great-grandfather as well and I would like to know if there are any other patents under his name and the status of this existing patent.  Never knew this existed and would appreciate any other information that may be available.

Comment: That patent would have expired more than 80 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can search here:

https://www.google.com/?tbm=pts#tbm=pts&q=ininventor%3A%22Ockrassa%22

http://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?ST=singleline&locale=en_EP&submitted=true&DB=worldwide.espacenet.com&query=Ockrassa

There are no other patents, other than the one design patent for a shoe.